# DB Select 2 ID's and Categories

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following code to listout the products from the database in my website, but if I want to select from 2 categories and ids, how this can be made?

```
$products = DB::select("SELECT * FROM products where category = 11 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
```

Comment: If you want to show products from specific categories you can use `WHERE category IN (11, 12)` or use your `SELECT` without `WHERE` for selecting from all categories

Answer (score 1):

Use IN Clause,

```
SELECT * FROM products where category IN (id1, id2) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to find your products according to multiple conditiions. Then use `AND` between your conditions:

```
$products = DB::select("SELECT * FROM products where category = 11 AND [your other condition] ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
```

Or you can use `in` if it's conditions from the same column.

https://www.garron.me/en/bits/mysql-select-multiple-conditions.html

Comment: Hello @jules R i did this: $products = DB::select("SELECT * FROM products where category = 11 AND [92] ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
but dosen't work

Comment: [your other condition] is the full condition, ie category = 92 (in this case use OR instead of AND). But `IN` is more appropriated for two conditions on the same column as Jekys suggested. So SELECT * FROM products where category IN (11, 92) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4